# Can I play the game Don't Starve on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, games, compatibility

I am new to Ubuntu. Bought an Acer C7 Chromebook yesterday and installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit tonight. I have seen 1 or 2 web sites that make me think you can play the game **Don't Starve** on Ubuntu. I was reading something about having to play it in Chrome with *NaCL* enabled.

I've searched and searched with no answers?! Is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, but you will need Ubuntu 12.10.

1. Download Steam from Ubuntu Software Center
2. Start it up, you will be asked to log in with your Steam account. If you don't have one you can choose the create account option.
3. Go to the Store tab
4. Enter Don't Starve in the search bar in the top-right and click Don't Starve
5. Scroll a bit down and click the green button to buy the game
6. Pay with credit card or PayPal. It costs €14
7. The game will be downloaded and installed
8. **Play :-D**

Comment: Why Ubuntu 12.10? Steam only officially supports 12.04 LTS and I run Steam fine on 13.04.

Comment: @minerz029 13.04 is fine too. But the system requirements of Don't Starve say 12.10 or higher is required.

Answer (score 0):

**Install from Chrome Webstore and play via Google Chrome**

Yes you can, altough Linux isn't officially supported according to the game's website ([system requirements](http://www.dontstarvegame.com/blog/system-requirements)), but the game is available in the *Chrome Webstore* for all platforms:

[Chrome Web Store - Don't Starve](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-starve/hiledapehlkhdehbhppgmekfalnlfajc)

**Note**: does not work on the Ubuntu builds of Chromium, because Native Client (NaCl) is disabled ([bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/882942)).

1. Open the above Chrome Webstore  link in `Google Chrome`.
2. Click ***Add to Chrome***.
3. You will be prompted to log in with a Google account - log in or create one and log in.
4. Answer ***Add*** to the confirmation question when asked.

Once installed, you can launch it from Chrome's *new tab page*. If it does not work, there might be an issue with your graphics card, its drivers and the WebGL support in Chrome.

Tested on: Chrome 30.0.1599.66, Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, Intel HD4000 Graphics (xserver-xorg-video-intel: 2:2.21.9-0ubuntu0~raring).

Comment: I have tested with chromium (seems unsupported) and chrome (seems bugged, keeps re-downloading and never starts) on ubuntu 12.10 and both fail :(

Comment: @AquariusPower Just tried (12.10, Chrome 30.0.1599.66), I got to the point where I could play: http://i.imgur.com/1txW86o.jpg I'd assume graphics card/WebGL issue. :| Contact the devs?

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu-built Chromium: installs fine (not visible in the search results though), but then when started, complains about Native Client support, which can't be enabled in the Ubuntu builds of Chromium.